# Receiving speech from discord audio channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to record speech in discord using python for my bot-helper. I  haven't found any documentation in official API reference, so it is a giant problem for me. I know it is possible with js, but what about python?

Comment: Please check [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: No, there's no high level API for that.  [You can see some of the discussion and proposed changes here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/1094).  I remember looking into this in the past, and there is a low level hook somewhere that you can read individual packets from, so you might look into that if you really need this functionality.